# Setting a select element option with a given value to be the selected option

Tags: jquery, html

In this jsfiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/3QrC4/3/ - I want to make the option that has the value "Calibri" the selected option.  But the last option  becomes the selected one.   Does anyone see the problem?

Thanks

```
$(function() {
    $('#fontname option').filter(function() {
        return value="Calibri";
    }).prop('selected', true);
})
```

Comment: main problem is using `=` instead of comparitive operator `===`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much simpler approach is just set the value of the `<select>` using `val()`

```
 $('#fontname').val("Calibri");/* pass in array if using a "multiple" select */
```

If you check the option `selected` properties it will return the expected results

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/3QrC4/7/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Try this code ([or try it on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QrC4/6/)):

```
$(function() {
    $('#fontname > option').filter(function() {
        return this.value === 'Calibri';
    }).prop('selected', true);
});
```

Inside the function, `value` is not defined.

However, `this` refers to the current element, so we get the `value` of it.

Also, you need to use `==` or `===` to compare two values in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3QrC4/5/)

Code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#fontname option').filter(function() {
        return this.value=="Calibri";
    }).prop('selected', true);
})
```

Inside your filter function, `this` refers to one element of the set, and the function will be run once per set. Whether the function returns true or false for that element determines whether it should be included in the set.

Note: `a=b` is the assignment operator, meaning "make a's value the same as b's". `a==b` is the loose equality operator, meaning "is the value of a equivalent to the value of b?"